# SignalR Core Client and Https working on localhost but not with computer name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I currently have a SignalR client app running under dot net framework 4.6.1 with Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client v1.0.0-preview1-final.

Here is my code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
var hubUrl = "https://localhost:44374/chat";
//var hubUrl = "https://MYCOMPUTERNAME:44374/chat";
var hubConnection = new HubConnection(new HttpConnection(new Uri(hubUrl)), new JsonHubProtocol(),null );
await hubConnection.StartAsync();
await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("send", "name var", "random message");
```

If I run it like above, using https over localhost, the message is broadcast, and I see it appear on my client.

But if I use the computer name in the url, https://MYCOMPUTERNAME:44374/chat, it fails on the StartAsync statement with:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 503 (Service Unavailable).'

Please note the very first line where I completely bypass https certificate checks, I will deal with that issue once I have it working.

I have gone directly to the url using the localhost https url https://localhost:44374/chat and it says: "Connection ID required" which is correct (I haven't provided the Connection ID). With the machine name version, it says

> "Service Unavailable - HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."

Switching back shows no problems, so I'm pretty sure the service is there.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: 503 means the server isn't listening on that name, only on localhost. How did you set up the server?

Comment: Well I didn't. It's my desktop machine at work. I was thinking something in there might be interfering, perhaps the firewall or virus software perhaps?

Comment: The firewall is fine if you connected and got a 503. Most likely the server is listening for the wrong host. You'll have to go figure out it's config.

Comment: If you're launching something like IIS Express from Visual Studio, it only listens on localhost and good luck convincing it otherwise.

Comment: I'll see how I go deploying it on the staging machine, which has a different configuration and real IIS.

Comment: Ok, I tried it on another environment and it worked without a problem, so it must be IIS express causing the issue.